# an interesting question on conditional probability

Tags: probability

If 4 integers are selected at random from the first 23 naturals then what is the probability that their product is even, if it is given that their sum is odd?
Since I have no idea about the process how to do I have referred to solution given in the book. 
It says " Since it is a certain event, it's probability=1" but I think it is not a certain event. Can you please clarify?

Comment: The sum of any four odd numbers is even, so if the sum of your numbers is odd at least one of them must be even.  So....

Comment: Since it might have taken a while already, an integer is even if its prime factorization has (at least) a $2$.